# How can I make money after finishing my career?

Tags: need-for-speed-carbon

I have completed the entire career mode, having won all races, but I want to get more money so I can buy other cars in career mode. How can I make more money?

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's no way to do this. The workaround I use to employ was taking a backup of the save (on PC), and then using my copy to sell whatever cars and make different cars to drive around in free roam with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways I have found to make money in campaign mode after completing the campaign are:

- **Redo races.** You complete races again to earn 500$ per win, and with Neville and Samson as crew members, you can earn an extra 250$ per win.
- **Rival crew member challenges.** Winning a challenge from a rival crew member will net you 1000$.